# How do I run this script with sudo from the command-line?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, python3

I have the following script in my user's bin directory; let's pretend the filename is 'myScript':

```
#!/bin/bash

python3 /myPath/myProgram.py "$@"
```

From the commandline, if I type `myScript`, it launches my myProgram.py. If I type `sudo myScript`, however it gives me this error: `sudo: myProgram: command not found`.

Why doesn't this work? How can I make it work?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tested `sudo /path/to/myScript`

Comment: @A.B. Sorry, I had a mistake in my question, which I edited out. It works if I'm in the bin directory and type `sudo ./myScript`. So, yes, with the full path it works. However, putting things in the bin directory makes it so you can run them without typing the path. So, I guess getting it to work with that functionality is what I'm asking about.

Comment: Add your local bin folder to the PATH environment.

Comment: @A.B. How do I do that? (So it persists after reboot, too.)

Comment: see this : http://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path

Comment: Edit your `~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably need to run the script like:

- `sudo /path/to/myScript`
- `sudo ./myScript` (if the script is in the current directory)

The reason you get `command not found` is the script is not in the current user's PATH directory. However, using `sudo` runs it as a different user - root (compare `echo $PATH` and `sudo -i` then `echo $PATH` to see). So of you want to add it to the root user's PATH:

- Copy it to `/usr/local/bin`, `/usr/bin/` or another direcotry already in the root's PATH
- [Add the directory to the PATH](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path), but do it as root (carefully).

Comment: This is a very good explanation, well done.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, but adding the script to /usr/local/bin and restarting didn't solve the problem (although it's in both my path and the root path). However, I decided to resort to update-alternatives (I already knew about that, but I thought there might be an easier way to do it without it: `update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/myScript myScript /home/myUsername/bin/myScript 0`